Incorrect location data after importing an asset
Hello i marked a curve object as asset after applying all the transforms

But after dragging it in a new scene it is offsetted 6 meters in Z space anyone know how to fix this?


You marked it at asset and then you drag it into a new scene... from the Asset Browser? Assets which you drag into a scene get the location where you drop them. They are not getting reset automatically. Try Alt+G to reset the location. But if an asset consists of many different objects that might not be what you want if they are not all on (0, 0, 0) in their default position. Usually you parent them to an empty which you can reset then. Apart from that it's hard to tell what's going on there, in the first screenshot there is one curve object selected, in the second many mesh objects.

hello i dragged the asset on the world origin but it;'s offseted 6m in z space for some reason that's the problem    manually resetting the object everytime isn't convenient
